# custom message for multiple column unique mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

***Objective:***

Create custom message for validation

***what i  tried***

my schema:

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    locationId: { type: String, required: true,index:true },
    stockingLocationId: { type: String, required: true,index:true},
    parentStockingLocationId: { type: String },
    stockingLocationDescription: { type: String },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now  },
    lastModified: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    isActive: { type: Boolean , default : true },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean , default : false }

});

locationSchema.index({locationId:1, stockingLocationId:1}, { unique: true });
```

I want to throw custom message for uniquess validation for the later line.

```
locationSchema.index({locationId:1, stockingLocationId:1}, { unique: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the **[mongoose-unique-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator)** package that adds pre-save validation for unique fields within a Mongoose schema and also makes error handling much easier, since you will get a Mongoose validation error when you attempt to violate a unique constraint, rather than an E11000 error from MongoDB:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    locationId: { type: String, required: true,index:true },
    stockingLocationId: { type: String, required: true,index:true},
    parentStockingLocationId: { type: String },
    stockingLocationDescription: { type: String },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now  },
    lastModified: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    isActive: { type: Boolean , default : true },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean , default : false }

});

locationSchema.index({locationId:1, stockingLocationId:1}, { unique: true });
locationSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: 'Error, expected {PATH} to be unique.' });
```